# Abstract baseclass: How to add a standard action after unique implementations of abstract method?

Tags: python, abstract-base-class

I'd like to reduce boiler plate code needed to implement my `FooBC` abstract baseclass for dataclasses. What the ABC needs to do:

- Every inheritor will be created slightly differently from (eg) a float, that's why each needs to implement the `from_float()` class method.
- but *all* inheritors should save `float_value / 2`. How can I automate this? Currently, the user is forced to paste `float_value / 2` in each implementation of `from_float()`.

Right now, this is my code:

```
# Abstract Base Class
@dataclass
class FooBC(ABC):
   always_save_half: float

@classmethod
@abstractmethod
def from_float(cls, value: float):
    pass

def __post_init__(self):
    """Allows inheritance by 'dataclasses'"""
    # just intercept the __post_init__ calls so they
    # aren't relayed to `object`

# Inheritor
@dataclass
class FooInheritor(FooBC):
    special_foo_result: float

    def from_float(cls, value: float):
        return cls(
            special_foo_result: value * 10,  # intended, unique use of 'from_foodata'
            ##### IDENTICAL FOR ALL INHERITORS; HOW CAN I GET RID OF THIS: #####
            always_save_half: value / 2,  
        )
```

I'd love to reduce the Inheritor boiler plate to:

```
# Inheritor
@dataclass
class FooInheritor(FooBC):
    special_foo_result: float

    def from_float(cls, value: float):
        return cls(
            special_foo_result: value * 10,  # intended, unique use of 'from_float'
        )
```

How can I upgrade the FooBC class to automatically save `float_value/2` whenever `from_float` is called?

I imagine something like this would be great:

```
# Abstract Base Class
@dataclass
class FooBC(ABC):
   _always_save_half: float = field(init=False, repr=False)

@classmethod
@abstractmethod
def from_float(cls, value: float):
    pass

@use_input.from_float  # my fantasy decorator, using from_float()'s input
def _init_after_from_float(value: float):
    self._always_save_half = value / 2

@property
def always_save_half() -> float:
    return self._always_save_half
...
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass value in all instances and add `always_save_half = value /2` in the super class init, and let the init of subclasses decide how it is processed further (e.g. in `special_foo_result`)?

Comment: @BramVanroy thanks, this our current solution. But in our case the input is not a `float` but a whole data container which we'd rather not save (and copy across all instances), that's why we have the `.from_float/datacontainer()` method in the first place.